# Why is anti-neutrino produced along side with electron in beta minus decay?

Tags: nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, radiation, neutrinos

so i get that when there is an excess of neutrons, neutron is converted into a proton. An electron is produced to neutralise the +1 charge of proton. But why is an anti neutrino produced?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neutron decay and electron anti neutrino $n\to p + e + \bar{\nu}_e$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31498/)

Answer (score 0):

The neutrinos were postulated by Pauli in order to have the conservation of energy, momentum and angular momentum in [beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay). The conversion of a neutron to a proton, an electron and an [(electron) antineutrino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_neutrino) is an example of a beta decay.

In these reactions, we have the conservation of [lepton number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton_number).
We had zero electrons and neutrinos before the decay of the neutron (lepton number $0$) and after the decay we have one proton (lepton number $0$), one electron (lepton number $+1$) and one (electron) antineutrino (lepton number $-1$). So, we have called that particle an antineutrino, and it has a negative lepton number.